# Pass parameters in URL to Django Admin add_view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to pass a parameter in the URL to the **Django Admin** `add` view, so that when I type the URL: `http://localhost:8000/admin/myapp/car/add?brand_id=1`, the `add_view` reads the `brand_id` parameter. I want to use this so that I can set a default value for the `brand` attribute of `Car`.

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(CarAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['brand'].initial = <<GET['brand_id']>>
    return form
```

Use case: I want this because in my `BrandsAdmin`, I have added a "+" button for each brand, that should add a `Car` with that `Brand` as FK.

I've tried getting it from `request` in `get_form`, but when that code is executed, Django has already changed my URL as I guess it doesn't understand it as a "legal" parameter.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly, for what I wanted to do, it's as easy as two steps.

First, add a column in `list_display` to show the link to the `add_view`:

**Brand.py**

```py
@admin.display(description='Link', ordering='url')
def get_add_link(self):
    url = f"{reverse('admin:myapp_car_add')}?brand={self.id}"
    return format_html(f"<a href='{url}'><i class='fas fa-plus'></i></a>")
```

Note that I add the URL as the reverse of `admin:<app>_<model>_<action>` and pass the brand ID as parameter.

**CarAdmin.py**

```py
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    brand_id = request.GET.get('brand')
    return {'brand': brand_id}
```

By adding this method in the `CarAdmin` class, I am able to set the brand as the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Using django 3 i did it overriding get_form in **CarAdmin.py** like you did, and its working for me, maybe the trick is in Brand.py:

**Brand.py**

```
readonly_fields = ('get_add_link',)
def get_add_link(self, obj):
  url = f"{reverse('admin:myapp_car_add')}?brand={self.id}"
  return format_html(f"<a href='{url}'><i class='fas fa-plus'></i></a>")
```

**CarAdmin.py**

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(CarAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    brand_id = request.GET.get('brand')
    if brand_id and len(brand_id) > 0:
        form.base_fields['brand'].initial = brand_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full explanation [here](https://pythoncircle.com/post/710/getting-query-params-from-request-in-django/), but shortly:

You can access query parameters directly from the view, the request object has a method. I suppose it is a GET request, so an example for your implementation would be:

```
request.GET.getlist("brand_id")
```

or

```
request.GET.get("brand_id")
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how to apply this. I want to get it in my default `edit_view` view, which I've only configured in the `CarAdmin` class.

Comment: oh but the request object is the one that is already passed to the view. you need to put this exactly where you higlighted, so
form.base_fields['brand'].initial = request.GET.get("brand_id")

Answer (score 0):

I did not have to do anything with the `Model`. The only change needed was in the `ModelAdmin`:

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
  brand = None
  brand_id = request.GET.get('brand')
  if (brand_id):
    brand = Brand.objects.get(id=brand_id)
  return {'brand': brand}
```

Docs link here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data